# django-cors-headers stop working for Django 1.6.11

Tags: django, angular

I'm currently using Angular4 with django-nonrel as the backend. Got the CORS error at the beginning and installed django-cors-headers to give django support for CORS. I had to install version 1.1.0 because django-nonrel supports
up to django 1.6.11. Everything was working perfectly so far for several weeks, but after I turned off my laptop today I started getting the CORS error again.

Django

> ConnectionFailure: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because
> the target machine actively refused it

Angular

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/pgla/project_list. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' is therefore not allowed
> access. The response had HTTP status code 500

I verify the installing instructions for the django-cors-headers module and everything is correct. Here are my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

And here is the hearder paremeter for Angular:

```
new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}),
```

Comment: The 500 status code mentioned in the error message indicates some server-side failure on the `http://127.0.0.1:8000` server. So you need to go in and look at the server logs on that server to find out what information is getting logged about the cause of that failure. The fact the browser is showing a CORS error message is just incidental—that’s only because the server doesn’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to 500 responses. The real problem is you’ve got something causing that 500 that you need to fix. Once you fix that, the CORS error will go away too

Answer (score 0):

Django corsheaders works with django 1.8 and above. Please upgrade your django version and then try again.

**Requirements**
Tested with all combinations of:

Python: 2.7, 3.6
Django: 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 2.0